# 'list' object has no attribute 'board'(Matrix)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class GameBoard(object):

    def __init__(self,blackp='X',whitep='O',counter=0):
            self.board

    def boardinit(self):
            self.board=[['+' for row in range(17)]for col in range(17)]
            def setboarder(self):
                    for hor in range(17):
                            self.board[0][hor]= board[16][hor]='--'
                    for side in range(17):
                            self.board[side][0]=board[side][16] = '|' 
                    return board
            self.board = setboarder(self.board)
```

I wonder how to initialize a matrix gameboard with the OOP, the example I found is from: https://github.com/ChenghaoQ/Pyex/blob/master/2048.py, in that case, where is the code  declares the **self.field**?

Comment: Is this your real indentation? If so, that is the problem. You defined an **internal function** to `boardinit`, so it doesn't get `self` as a first argument. It gets what you pass in, which is `self.board`, meaning your `self.board` inside it is calling `self.board.board`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You should make this the answer

Comment: @ Two-Bit Alchemist, do you mean i need to move the setboard out of the boardinit(self) or just move the ? or how to pass the self.board into the setboarder() if keeps the indentation

Comment: You should move it out of boardinit IMO. No reason it should be an inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `self.board.board` upon passing it to the inner function. This is a better approach, which will run faster and be less buggy:

```
def boardinit(self):
    board=[['+' for row in range(17)]for col in range(17)]
    # Set border
    for hor in range(17):
        board[0][hor]= board[16][hor]='--'
    for side in range(17):
        board[side][0]=board[side][16] = '|'

    self.board = board
```

Comment: Do i have to declare self.board in the __init__?

Comment: @C.Qian No, you do not. It is a good practice though to declare it with None being the value. Someone looking at your code may know straight that this attribute exists.